# Scanning external jar java datasource configuration in a multimodule SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I would like to ask on how to configure the SpringBoot application to include external Jar Java DataSource Configuration. Entity classes are all annotated with `@Entity` in the external Jar entity classes, repository interfaces with @ repository annotation with CrudRepository extended. The Lib module is packaged as a JAR file with Datasource configured in Java. The WAR module is supposed to import the LIB jar, and use it to extract data from database, with the datasource configured with the JAR itself.

Maven build extract

```
<groupId>com.sample.app</groupId>
<artifactId>App-war</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sample.lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>Lib-jar</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.penta.account</groupId>
            <artifactId>AccountService-jar</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have tried the following method below which resulted in 'not a managed type' error for entity class. I understand that @EnableJpaRepository and @EntityScan is supposed to scan external JAR Spring beans to be included in the WAR application.

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.sample.lib.repository","com.sample.app.repository"})
@EntityScan({"com.sample.lib.entity","com.sample.app.entity"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application .class, args);
    }
}
```

So I thought that I should have imported the Java datasource configuration, and then use it to store the packages to scan. The application can be compiled but the components in the WAR were not compiled, resulting spring boot to use the default login page and ignoring any custom authentication in the WAR packages.

DataSource Java configuration for LibDSConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.sample.lib.repository")
public class LibDSConfig {

    // Other @Bean classes
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(local());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{com.sample.lib.entity});
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }    
}
```

DataSource Java configuration for AppDSConfig

```
@Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories("com.sample.app.repository")
    public class AppDSConfig {
    
        // Other @Bean classes
        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            em.setDataSource(local());
            em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{com.sample.app.entity});
            JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
            em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
            return em;
        }    
    }
```

Springboot main java configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@ComponentScan({"com.sample.lib.entity","com.sample.lib.entity"})
@Import({
    AppDSConfig.class,
    LibDSConfig .class
})
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I understand that the @ComponentScan only scans the entity classes as configured in the code above. I would like to ask if there are any alternative solutions to import external jar java configurations?

Comment: Can you remove ComponentScan from the Application and see if things are working fine?

Comment: @sonus21 If I removed ComponentScan, Springboot will not process EnableJpaRepositories in the java datasource config file. If i add EnableJpaREpositories in the springboot main app, it will throw not a managed type error.

Comment: @sonus21 I just found out the issue that I forgot to import the module in maven. Thanks for the help anyway!! Cheers